# App crashing with Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) when trying to create sine wave audio above 12000KHz

Tags: android, audio, sigabrt, audiotrack

I am trying to create sine wave audio from 20Hz-20KHz. I am only able to create sine wave till 12KHz. After that the app is crashing with the following error

> A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 30692 (AudioTrack), pid 30615 (SineWaveGenerator)

Attaching the code I used.

*MainActivity*

```
Thread waveGeneratorThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (frequency >= 20 && frequency <= 20000) {
            wave.setWave((int) frequency);
            boolean on = tb1.isChecked();
            if (on) {
                wave.start();
            } else {
                wave.stop();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

*PlayWave Java Class*

```
private final int sampleRate = 192000;
private AudioTrack audioTrack;
int buffersize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate,
        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
private int sampleCount;

public PlayWave() {
    audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            sampleRate,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            buffersize,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
}

public void setWave(int frequency) {
    sampleCount = (int) ((float) sampleRate / frequency);
    short samples[] = new short[sampleCount];
    int amplitude = 32767;
    double twopi = Math.PI * 2;
    double phase = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sampleCount; i++) {
        samples[i] = (short) (amplitude * Math.sin(phase));
        phase += twopi * frequency / sampleRate;

    }
    audioTrack.write(samples, 0, sampleCount);
}

public void start() {
    audioTrack.reloadStaticData();
    audioTrack.setLoopPoints(0, sampleCount, -1);
    audioTrack.play();
}

public void stop() {
    audioTrack.stop();
}
```

Comment: What is the sampleRate?

Comment: First tried with 44100 Hz . But the app crashes after producing 8KHz..Then tried with 192000Hz , then wave till 12KHz were produced.